# Spacemacs: change prefix key from `SPC-b` to `SPC-v`

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, prefix-keys

I use buffer (`SPC-b`) prefix key very often, and would like to move its keymap to a more convenient key (e.g. `SPC-v`). Is there a way to achieve this without redefining the entire map?

so I would like to move:

- `SPC-b-b` to `SPC-v-b`
- `SPC-b-d` to `SPC-v-d`

etc...

Comment: Edited to express the question in terms of prefix keys, guessing that's what you mean. I'm not familiar with Spacemacs, so if this is not correct please reverse the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `SPC-b` is a prefix key (I don't use Spacemacs), just bind the key you want, which I guess is `SPC-v`, to whatever `SPC-b` is currently bound to.  Then, if you want to unbind `SPC b` just bind it to `nil`.

The command that `SPC-b` is currently bound to is what this returns:

```
(symbol-function (key-binding (kbd "SPC-b")))
```

So just use this, to bind `SPC-v` to the same command (which is presumably also a keymap):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "SPC-v") (symbol-function (key-binding (kbd "SPC-b"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so.

I read some source code of spacemacs, you can change the leader keys easily, however, the keys after leader keys are hard coded.

BTW, you should better not mess up those keys, since it will conflict with other key bindings. And, you can have your own key bindings with prefix `o`. In addition, the default spacemacs key bindings is intuitive and easy to remember.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I completely agree with that you're saying. This is a good choice for the spacemacs, and is definitely "easier". But I would still prefer swapping "b" and "v". I use b a lot more than v and I'm sure I can come up with a mnemonic which work "well enough" to trick my brain into remembering them. Do you know if there a "hacky" way to do it? For example, can read all the keybindings starting with "b", and remap them in a loop?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know someone has done this. However, since you already have a clue, you can try it yourself.